# Get item by relative path in AzureDevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have a file in git repository which contains links on other files. A content from this file I can get by GitHttpClient.GetItemAsync as:

```
client.GetItemAsync(projectName, repositoryName, path: path,
            versionDescriptor: new GitVersionDescriptor {Version = branch})
```

Then I'm trying to get items by links from this file but if path is relative, for example "../../test/test.txt", i don't get anything.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Git doesn't understand the concept of "paths" -- it's the same reason you can't have an empty folder in Git. You must specify an explicit full path.

Comment: Can I get the folder structure of the repository?

Comment: Yes, kind of. It's called a "tree", and there are APIs for it.